# (2, 2, 1) array dimensions to 2*2 matrix

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy

I obtained this results which I expected to be a 2*2 matrix, but it has `(2, 2, 1)` dimensions instead:

```
[[array([0.53281666]), array([0.51876626])], [array([0.53281666]), array([0.51876626])]]
```

How can i convert it to 2*2 matrix and how can i invers it in Python ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inverse it" here? Do you mean to get the inverse of the matrix?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Take a look at [numpy.squeeze](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to remove the last axis

Comment: you probably just want `.reshape()`; you can call `dir()` to inspect the methods on any object!

Comment: You actually want `array([[value1, value2], [value3, value4]])`.

Comment: @Seon Thank you i used it and now i want to invert the matrix but i got the error " "Singular matrix "

Comment: @EwanBrown Yes, i want to get the inverse of the matrix  [[0.53281666 0.51876626]
 [0.53281666 0.51876626]] but i got an erroe " Singular matrix"

Comment: Is the shape really `(2,2,1)`?  It looks more like an object dtype array with shape (2,2).  Or maybe it's a nested list.  Your display is ambiguous.

Comment: with those numbers, the array is `singular`; the two rows are the same.  The determinante is 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To remove axes of length one, you can use `numpy.squeeze`:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[0.53281666], [0.51876626]], [[0.53281666], [0.51876626]]])
arr = arr.squeeze()
```

You will then get a 2x2 matrix.

To invert a numpy array, you can use `np.linalg.inv(arr)`. In your case however, the matrix is singular (ie non-invertible), so this function call will raise an error.